# Ember (Computed?) Property that runs a function on .set()

Tags: ember.js

I have something similar to this code below:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.mixin.create({
    maxPosition: 100,
    minPosition: 0,
    position: 0,
    updatePosition: function(increment){
        this.set('position', increment);
    }
});
```

This code is super simplified for clarity, but I want to put bounds of `minPosition` and `maxPosition` on `position`

For Example:

If I run: `this.updatePosition(150);`

and then run `this.get('position')`

it should return `100`

Can I make `position` into a computed property that will be bound by these values when I run `this.set()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try, but [documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties) says it is possible. Something like this should work:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.mixin.create({
    maxPosition: 100,
    minPosition: 0,
    _pos: 0,
    position: Ember.computed('_pos', {
      get: function(key) {
        return this.get('_pos');
      },
      set: function(key, value) {
        var pos = Math.max(Math.min(value, this.get('maxPosition')), this.get('minPosition'));
        this.set('_pos', pos);
        return pos;
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know you could define the .set() for a computed property thanks!

Comment: Actually, this doesn't treat position as a normal computed property. For example if another computed property depends on `position` it won't be updated because it doesn't detect that `position` was updated.

Comment: It's weird. According to the [documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_chaining-computed-properties), If you set a property by calling `something.set('position', 100);`, ember should update depending properties.  But there is a method, [notifyPropertyChange](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_notifyPropertyChange). Try to add `this.notifyPropertyChange('position');` into `set` method and look if it helps.